# Can I purchase just the Skylanders disk, without the starter pack?

Tags: nintendo-wii, skylanders

We purchased the Swap Force starter pack; the kids have figures from that, giants & swap force, all which play on the original portal. Now they have completed Swap Force game, I am hoping to buy another disk, but must I buy an entire starter pack with a new portal? It is my understanding that only the Trap Team figures need their own portal, and so far all of our figures (no trap team ones) have worked great on the original Swap Force portal... Do I have to buy another Giants/Spyros Adventure/etc. Starter Pack with a new portal?? (Original Wii console)

Answer (score 2):

Swap force actually includes the second portal. The original Skylanders and Giants uses a different portal (I have not tried to see if the Swapforce one is backwards compatible).

Originally the first game was only available new with the portal (since there was no reason to buy the game seperate) you may be able to find just the disk used. However Giants had two packages, one that included a portal and another that did not. (again you may need the old portal to play).